# Can I get reports from firebase real time database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display information on my web app that came from data stored in my real time database, such as how many users are stored. is it possible with firebase real time database only since I stored everything there?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not have any reporting mechanism - you will need to build a custom solution.  If you need any data at all from your database, you will need to be able to construct a query for it.  That means you will have to record the data you need for your custom report.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show me an example for a query that can be displayed in my custom reports? I can't find anything anywhere.

Comment: That sounds like another question, where you should show some sample data along with whatever code you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  Firebase doesn't have a way to count child nodes, so if that's what you want, then you'll have to maintain a count yourself somehow.

Comment: Ok I'll see what I can do. thank you very much.